# Change result set order based on another column being null

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that sorts the results based on the second column.

```
select decode(name, null, 'n/a', name) name, value1
from tableA
group by name
order by 2
```

How can I change it so a result where the first column is null is always the last row in the result set, without changing the ordering for the rest of the results?

One solution I have in my mind is to use union two queries, one which excludes nulls and one which only has nulls, something like:

```
select decode(name, null, 'n/a', name) name, value1
from tableA
where name is not null
group by name
union
select decode(name, null, 'n/a', name) name, value1
from tableA
where name is null
group by name
order by 2
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: there is no such thing in Oracle like n-th row or last row unless you use the "order by" clause. The row which was inserted as the last one could be placed in one of data blocks in the middle which had enough free space...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `union` approach won't get the result you want; the `order by` is applied after the two queries are unioned, so they will be sorted the same as if you had a single query. You could add a flag column in each brach of the union and include that in the ordering, but the you need to exclude it from the final select list.

You can handle this in the `order by clause`, using a case statement (or decode if you prefer) against column 1 which treats all not-null values as one priority regardless of the actual value, and all null values as a different priority; and then further orders by column 2:

```
select decode(a.name, null, 'n/a', a.name) name, value1
from tableA a
order by case when a.name is null then 1 else 0 end, value1 desc
```

I've used a table alias and included that in the case to avoid confusion between the original table value and the column alias of the same name. This will put all the results with null ('n/a') names after all of those which are not null; and within each category all the results will still be sorted by the second column.

With some sample data:

```
with tableA (name, value1) as (
  select 'Joe', 3 from dual
  union all select 'Anne', 10 from dual
  union all select null, 4 from dual
  union all select 'Sarah', 2 from dual
  union all select 'Bill', 5 from dual
  union all select 'Mary', 7 from dual
)
```

... ordering just by the second column gets:

```
select decode(a.name, null, 'n/a', a.name) name, value1
from tableA a
order by value1 desc;

NAME      VALUE1
----- ----------
Anne          10
Mary           7
Bill           5
n/a            4
Joe            3
Sarah          2
```

Adding this case clause puts your 'n/a' row last in the result set:

```
select decode(a.name, null, 'n/a', a.name) name, value1
from tableA a
order by case when a.name is null then 1 else 0 end, value1 desc;

NAME      VALUE1
----- ----------
Anne          10
Mary           7
Bill           5
Joe            3
Sarah          2
n/a            4
```

(I've ignored the group by clause in your example because you don't have any aggregates, and neither of your queries is valid; but you can still group and do this in your real query if you need to.)

Comment: The order priority is on column 2 desc, since column 1 value falls in that order, I need to extract the row where the column1 value is null and then append it at the bottom, i don't want to disrupt the order on 2nd column. 
I don't need a case statement for your case, I can do `order by 1 nulls last` will give me the result you have given me

Comment: This won't disrupt the column2 order with each null/not null block. And this is not the same as `order by 1 nulls last`; that takes each individual value into account then ordering. With the case it's a binary null/not null flag. It will put the row(s) where the first column is null at the end of the result set.

Comment: apologies, you are right, I overlooked the values.. I did value1 desc for that order